I have a continuous instrument and a multi-valued treatment in a 2SLS, what's the gold standard?
So as the title says I have a setting with a continuous instrument and a multi-valued treatment in a 2SLS. I'm browsing the literature trying to find out the current gold standard for estimating a treatment effect, but I see a lot of different methods pointing in different directions. Does anyone econometrically inclined know the current status of the methods?

Can you elaborate on the treatment variable: is it ordered, continuous, categorical, etc.? What about the outcome?

Thank you for responding! Sorry I should have been more clear in my original post.
The treatment variable is discrete and ordered, whereas the outcome variable is  continuous. So the setup is a 2SLS with a continuous instrument, a discrete ordered treatment variable and a continuous outcome variable.

Isn't this, then, a typical 2SLS setup?

Is a monotonicity assumption plausible: higer values of instrument Z -> higher categorical values of treatment X?

Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find
information on how to do this in the My Account
section of our [help]), then you will be able to
edit & comment on your own question.

@dimitriy Yes it's very plausible.

@Dave As far as I understand it 2SLS is known to not identify LATE even with a binary instrument when including covariates, and a multi-valued treatment seems even harder to interpret. I'm therefore looking for what's the current gold standard in the field for this setting. I see some papers pushing the MTE framework whenever the instrument is continuous, but that seems to require a lot of assumptions - and I'm not sure if that's universally considered good in this setup either.
